# How can you apply AVG() on a row instead of a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a procedure that is fetching data from the DB and as an example the final result is the following:

```
Column1 |Column2         |Column3       |Column4     |Column5     |Column6
--------|----------------|--------------|------------|------------|-------
 1      |2               |1111          |001         |345.000000  |22
 3      |5               |1111          |001         |700.000000  |22
 1      |0               |1112          |001         |345.000000  |22
 2      |7               |5454          |001         |1200.000000 |22
 2      |5               |2364          |001         |1350.000000 |22
```

I'd like to apply the AVG function per row meaning I'd like to add a 7th column under which the AVG of all the values of column 1,2,3,4,5 and 6 for that specific row is "averaged"

Please note that some of the data can be nullable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One additional option is `VALUES` table value constructor:

```
SELECT 
   t.*,
   Column7 = (
      SELECT AVG(x) 
      FROM (VALUES (Column1), (Column2), (Column3), (Column4), (Column5), (Column6)) v(x)
   )
FROM YourTable t
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use arithmetic:

```
select (column1 + column2 + column3 + column4 + column5 + column6) / 6
```

If you want to add this to the table, you can use a computed column:

```
alter table t add column column7 as 
    (column1 + column2 + column3 + column4 + column5 + column6) / 6);
```

I should note that if any of the values are `NULL`, the returned value will be `NULL`.  That can be fixed, but all your sample data is non-`NULL`.

Comment: thanks! But, is there any way for the values to NOT be considered when they are a NULL? I mean like for the AVG function, when a value is null, it's skipped.

Comment: @HoussemTimoumi - you can add where class to ignore null,  where column1 is not null and column2 is not null etc...

Comment: but the division will be always a 6 which will affect the mathematical result

Answer (score 0):

> but the division will be always a 6 which will affect the mathematical result – Houssem Timoumi

you must wirte a little bit more:

```
alter table t add  column7 as 
( ( ISNULL (column1, 0)
  + ISNULL (column2, 0)
  + ISNULL (column3, 0)
  + ISNULL (column4, 0)
  + ISNULL (column5, 0)
  + ISNULL (column6, 0)
  )  
  / CASE  WHEN column1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END  
  + CASE  WHEN column2 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END  
  + CASE  WHEN column3 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END  
  + CASE  WHEN column4 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END  
  + CASE  WHEN column5 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END  
  + CASE  WHEN column6 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END  
);
```